# Is there any way to retrieve all data to the firebase Recycler Adapter, edit it then write it to another database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am working on an attendance app. Basically, I have already made the database of all the info needed and I can retrieve it to the firebase adapter. However, every time I tried to set the value on the attendance and send it to the other database it will only show one data.

Record show's only Mark (no John):
[image: Record show's only Mark (no John)]

[This is the attendance radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC1Ko.png)

```
   optionAttendanceData = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AttendanceCustom>()
    .setQuery(mQueryAttendanceData, AttendanceCustom.class).build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapterAttendanceData = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AttendanceCustom, AttendanceDataCustomViewHolder>(optionAttendanceData) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AttendanceDataCustomViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AttendanceCustom model) {
            
            holder.setDetails(model.getFirstName(), model.getLastName());
            firstName = model.getFirstName();
            lastName = model.getLastName();
            attendance = model.getAttendance();
            description = model.getDesctiption();
            date = model.getDate();
            
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public AttendanceDataCustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            mViewAttendanceData = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_attendance_data, parent, false);
            return new AttendanceDataCustomViewHolder(mViewAttendanceData);
        }
    };

    mRecyclerViewAttendanceData.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapterAttendanceData);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapterAttendanceData.startListening();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapterAttendanceData.notifyDataSetChanged();    
}

public class AttendanceDataCustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public AttendanceDataCustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mViewAttendanceData = itemView;            
    }

    private void setDetails(String first, String last) {
        TextView tv_first = mViewAttendanceData.findViewById(R.id.tv_attendance_data_first_name);
        TextView tv_last = mViewAttendanceData.findViewById(R.id.tv_attendance_data_last_name);

        tv_first.setText(first);
        tv_last.setText(last);
        radioButtonAttendance();    
    }

    public void sendData(){
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(10000);
        DatabaseReference dataRefAttendance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance").child("Record");
        AttendanceCustom attendanceCustom = new AttendanceCustom(firstName, lastName, date, description, attendance, numberDate);
        newKey = dataRefAttendance.child("Attendance").child("record").push().getKey();
        dataRefAttendance.child(firstName + "-" + lastName + "-" + randomNumber).setValue(attendanceCustom);
    }
```

Comment: You need to iterate through each position index of your Model. It only gets the last one or the first one in your case.
And are your sure your push() method for random int is working properly?

Comment: Yes it is, which is the number beside Mark-Styles on the image. I put random numbers to avoid overriding it.  Can you give me more info or even a clue on how to iterate?

Comment: You can declare the model as a List<> and use a for loop on your model. You can find more info on how to do it in the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you run this code in a debugger and step through it, which is the first line that doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: (Please Checked only the first name disregard the numbers and last name) 


What I did was I retrieve all children under info, which is John and Mark (Shows on the image above) to Firebase Recycler Adapter. Then I added some data on the Firebase Recycler Adapter (on the info data Mark and John), then I put the value under record, as you notice it shows only Mark. John wasn't added.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The radio button selection is not working properly radioButtonAttendance()

Whenever I use the radio button it will only affect the last item of the recyclerView.